# mysql: unique value in a field with respect to another field

Tags: mysql, database

suppose I have a database table with 3 fields col1, col2, col3
say, col1 is the primary index.

I konw that we can set a field as unique.

can I do something in structure that col3 should be unique with respect to col2, that is, for a value in col2, there cannot be 2 same values in col3.

or I have do do this validation in server side before passing the data to database?

example--
(1,10,3)
(2,10,4)
(3,11,3)
is valid, but
(1,10,3)
(2,10,4)
(3,11,3)
(4,11,3)
is invalid.

one possible solution that came to my mind that--
store the value of col2 and col3 in a separate field like "col2value-col3value" and make that field unique.

I am using mysql.

I am a newbie. so, a little details would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make the combination of `col2`, `col3` unique.  This does *not* require making them a primary key.  I would do it my creating a unique index on the pair:

```
create unique index idx_tbl_col2_col3 on (col2, col3)
```

As a note:  `NULL` values are ignored for this purpose.  So, you would still be allowed to have identical values, if one is `NULL`.  One option is to declare the columns `NOT NULL`.  Another would be to use triggers to prevent duplicates.

Comment: Thank you. :-) I really don't know much about mysql. But I like how you people here spread your hand to solve a problem. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The concept of primary key can be extended to more than one column.
You can find this referenced also as [Composite Primary Key](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx).

You need to add col2 and col3 to the set of primary key

In this way there can't be a record with col2 and col3 equal to another record already available in the table

In creation phase, please define the table in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (column1 INT NOT NULL, column2 INT NOT NULL, column3 INT NOT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY(column1, column2, column3))
```

Additional informations can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Comment: composite unique key and composite primary key. that's what I learned today. thank you. :-) I didn't know the term. otherwise, I could have googled... :-D

Comment: If i have to be honest Gordon answer does model better what you had in mind!